# Getting data from MS SQL database to Lotus Notes Database

Tags: sql-server, database, integration, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I know this is a weird thing to do and the question would be asked, why...
Anyhow, I have a project being started in association with integration and I was thinking about asking the question here to get a little think tank going and probably find the first "string/line" to pull on to get this tangled web to start unfolding in my head.

I know that Lotus Notes/domino DB is not a relational database and that the work to get it to work with an MS-SQL-database has been documented and talked about around the net. Also that probably every single case is unique.

But what's asked here is for the MS-SQl-Database information/data to be imported to Lotus Notes Database in some way. I don't have a Totally clear picture of how the information will be used exactly, but what I am looking for is the integration part between the two databases.

What is an effective way of doing this? Is it through the use of some kind of API or endpoint technique or maybe through some file export(example CSV-file) > Storage (example FTP) > import (example CSV-file)?

---EDIT----
This will be a periodically import of data.
Also just out of curiosity would this be able to be done as an "on demand" import?

---

I would very much appreciate any kind of ideas, brainstorming or suggestions!

Comment: Is this a one-time import? Or do you need to do an import and then periodically re-import? Or an import and then real-time synch (one direction, or both directions)?

Comment: Ah forgot to mention that, it will most likely be a periodically import.

Comment: How much tables should be  imported in Domino? What type of use/request should be performed on the data?

Answer (score 2):

There are lots and lots of options.

If your organization has [Lotus Enterprise Integrator](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/ibmenterpriseintegrator) licensed, I'd look at that because its purpose in life is to connect Domino to database systems for exports, imports, synchronization, etc. Otherwise, I might look at (believe it or not) Tivoli Directory Integrator, which is a [free entitlement for Domino customers](https://www-01.ibm.com/software/lotus/notesanddomino/additionalswentitlements.html); it's not really just for directories and it can [connect to SQL Server](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/tivoli/library/t-sqlitdi/). And you could, of course, just code it as an agent the Domino side using the [Lotus Connectors LSX](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_971200WORKING_WITH_THE_LSX.html) - which may or may not be easier than using TDI, and is certainly more lightweight.

Comment: You can write code to do it (in LotusScript or java) but it's a bit of a pain though.  I second the suggestion of LEI.  And it does so much more than just imports/exports, so you'd have an awesome tool in your arsenal.